# Bootstrap Center two progress bars with limited width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I'm trying to center two progress bars over an HTML canvas element.

[image]

I've tried various Bootstrap classes, and CSS changes and I just cant make it work unless I just add to the left bars margin. Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="scoreBoardLeft" class="col-xs-6 text-right"><a href="#" id="leftScore" class="btn btn-default"></a></div>
        <div id ="scoreBoardRight" class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" id="rightScore" class="btn btn-default"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 45%"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 45%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="pong" class="col-xs-12 text-center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0; 
}

canvas {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#scoreBoardLeft {
    padding-right: 1px;
}

#scoreBoardRight {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

#leftScore {
    width: 35px !important;
}

#rightScore {
    width: 35px !important;
}


.progress {
    margin-bottom: 1px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in that you set:

```
.progress {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

The `!important` flag is overwriting the `width:50%` for `col-xs-6` set by BootStrap.

Simply removing this line seems to fix this problem :)

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this, which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/yfngorsd/).

Hope this helps!

**Edit To Limit Width:**

The problem with limiting the width with your current markup is that you would need to set margins on the same class as the Bootstrap column, which would push the elements to the next line with your current HTML markup.

I'd recommend replacing:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 45%"></div>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 45%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By adding in this new div and changing the structure as above, you could modify the `width` of `.progress` as you were trying to do in the first place, and it would have the desired effect :)

I've created a new fiddle, changed this, and given the bars a width of 30% to reflect the change I think you're looking for :)

The new fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/7e9whc8L/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But now that the progress bars are centered how can I limit their width, will I need to add extra columns to the left and right to fill that space.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how the bars can have limited width. Ironically, it actually means reverting back to what you were essentially doing in the first place, and simply slightly changing the HTML. Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue I had to disable responsiveness within bootstrap. I then set the width of my grid container equal to that of my canvas element.

Boostrap was probably not the best choice since I did not want a responsive grid, lesson learned.

[Diable bootstrap responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)